# How to convert date format in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, formatting, strftime

Here are some outputs:

```
Date.today  => Mon, 25 Jun 2012 
Date.today.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)  => "June 25th, 2012" 
Date.today.strftime('%A %d, %B')  =>  "Monday 25, June"
```

Now I need output in the format ie:

```
  Monday 25th, June      or       Thrusday, 1st, October
```

Problem is **to_formatted_s** and **strftime** apply only on date and both or them return string. How can I get the output in the way I need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Date::DATE_FORMATS` to add a new customized format, and `Integer.ordinalize` to get the day ordinal:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:month_ordinal] = lambda { |date| 
  date.strftime("%A #{date.day.ordinalize}, %B") 
}

>> Date.today.to_formatted_s(:month_ordinal)
=> "Monday 25th, June"
```