# Formatting a date object to display a human readable date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, format

Here's what I'd like to display:

```
May 13, 2012
```

Here's what is being displayed:

```
2012-05-13
```

I searched for some answers and it led me to "[Formatting Dates and Floats in Ruby](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/formatting-dates-and-floats-in-ruby/)", where it mentions a possible solution:

```
<p class="date"><%= @news_item.postdate.to_s("%B %d, %Y") %></p>
```

However this doesn't change the output at all. No debugging errors, or exceptions are fired.

I can do this and it works perfectly fine:

```
<p class="date"><%= Time.now.to_s("%B %d, %Y") %></p>
```

Here is my migration file (to see what data type I used):

```
class CreateNewsItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :news_items do |t|

      t.date :postdate

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`Date.to_s` is not the same as `Time.to_s`. Your `postdate` is a `Date`, so therefore you might want to look at [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) instead:

```
postdate.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Or even look to add your own custom date format to your Rails app:
[Need small help in converting date format in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184305/need-small-help-in-converting-date-format-in-ruby)

Comment: One minor note: `strftime("%B %-d, %Y")` is a bit nicer for human readability. The `%-d` removes the leading 0, i.e. May 06, 2013 => May 6, 2013.

Answer (score 57):

The [to_formatted_s](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) function already has some common human readable formats for `DateTime` objects in Rails.

```
datetime.to_formatted_s(:db)            # => "2007-12-04 00:00:00"
datetime.to_formatted_s(:short)         # => "04 Dec 00:00"
datetime.to_formatted_s(:long)          # => "December 04, 2007 00:00"
datetime.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)  # => "December 4th, 2007 00:00"
datetime.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)        # => "Tue, 04 Dec 2007 00:00:00 +0000"
datetime.to_formatted_s(:iso8601)       # => "2007-12-04T00:00:00+00:00"
```

Comment: which is aliased to _to_s_.

Comment: it is now aliased to `to_fs`

Answer (score 8):

```
<%= time_ago_in_words @user.created_at %>
```

result: 9 hours ago

Comment: this is much nicer

Answer (score 2):

**To convert `created_at` time to a human-readable format, follow the below steps:**

1. First, convert it to local time like(UTC to local time)

   ```
   time_stmap = @user.created_at.localtime
   ```
2. For the time

   ```
   time_stmap.strftime("%I:%M %p")
   ```
3. For the date

   ```
   time_stmap.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
   ```